# TikZ pyramid hierarchy colour

Tags: tikz-pgf, color

I have a Ti*k*Z pyramid hierarchy, however I was wondering whether there was a way of filling the different tiers with colours. My current code is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (A) at (-5,0) {};
\coordinate (B) at ( 5,0) {};
\coordinate (C) at (0,7) {};
\draw[name path=AC] (A) -- (C);
\draw[name path=BC] (B) -- (C);
\foreach \y/\A in {0/Non-League, 1.5/League Two,2.5/ League One,3.5/Championship,4.5/Premier League} {
    \path[name path=horiz] (A|-0,\y) -- (B|-0,\y);
    \draw[name intersections={of=AC and horiz,by=P},
          name intersections={of=BC and horiz,by=Q}] (P) -- (Q)
        node[midway,above] {\A};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have two ways of doing the fill, but actually there is a much simpler way to draw your pyramid. We basically define a triangle that clips all the filled rectangles we position. Plus an extra fill for the last element of your foreach.

The first way includes a list of colors in an array. We add a `count` to your foreach and use that to select the colors. Since the array has an automatic numerical index `0,1,2,3,...`, we used the count for that.

The second way instead uses the count to draw a gradation, thanks to the `evaluate` option, multiplying the count by a certain number. Now, if you have 10 rectangles, it's best to do `count*10` so each rectangle is

```
color1!0!color2
color1!10!color2
color1!20!color2
color1!30!color2
```

And so on. But you can select any number, as long as you're happy with the result. For this last solution you can also use a single color of course, `color!##` which is short for `color!##!white` so that the higher the number, the more it's mixed with white.

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,backgrounds}
\begin{document}

% List of colors
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\colorlist{{"cyan", "red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "gray", "blue", "violet"}}

\foreach \y/\A [count=\xi starting from 0, evaluate=\y as \nexty using (\y+1.5, evaluate=\xi as \grad using int(\xi*15)] in {0/Non-League, 1.5/League Two,2.5/ League One,3.5/Championship,4.5/Premier League} {%
    \pgfmathsetmacro\myfill{\colorlist[\xi]}
    \begin{scope}[on background layer]
    \clip[preaction={draw}] (-5,0) -- (5,0) -- (0,7) -- cycle;
    \fill[\myfill] (-5,\y) rectangle (5,\nexty);
    \fill[\myfill] (-5,4.5) rectangle (5,7);
    \end{scope}
    \node at (0,\y+.3) {\A};
}
\end{tikzpicture}

% Gradations
\begin{tikzpicture}[xshift=5cm]
\foreach \y/\A [count=\xi starting from 0, evaluate=\y as \nexty using (\y+1.5, evaluate=\xi as \grad using int(\xi*15)] in {0/Non-League, 1.5/League Two,2.5/ League One,3.5/Championship,4.5/Premier League} {%
    \begin{scope}[on background layer]
    \clip[preaction={draw}] (-5,0) -- (5,0) -- (0,7) -- cycle;
    \fill[red!\grad!yellow] (-5,\y) rectangle (5,\nexty);
    \fill[red!\grad!yellow] (-5,4.5) rectangle (5,7);
    \end{scope}
    \node at (0,\y+.3) {\A};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @DanielRawlings In case you didn't know, if the answer solved your problem, consider ticking it as the accepted answer by clicking on the √ near the top left.

Answer (score 9):

Using simple triangle paths, we can fill the paths with predetermined colors or with gradients as a function of the counter `\i` of the loop below. `x` and `y` can be changed for best appearance.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=2.5cm,y=2cm]
\coordinate (A) at (-3,-1) {};
\coordinate (B) at (3,-1) {};
\coordinate (C) at (0,5) {};
\foreach \A/\col [count=\i] in {Non-League/green, League Two/cyan,League One/yellow,Championship/blue,Premier\\League/orange}
\draw[fill=\col] (C)--([shift={(-.5*\i,1*\i)}]B)--node[above,align=center] {\A}([shift={(.5*\i,1*\i)}]A)--cycle; 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Or as gradients like this:

```
\foreach \A/\col [count=\i,evaluate=\i as \j using 10*\i] in {Non-League, League Two,League One,Championship,Premier\\League}
\draw[fill=red!\j] (C)--([shift={(-.5*\i,1*\i)}]B)--node[above,align=center] {\A}([shift={(.5*\i,1*\i)}]A)--cycle;
```

[image]

Comment: How can I invert the colour gradient? Say, I want the top has the lightest colour, while the bottom has be deepest colour.

Answer (score 1):

I'm very late to this party. I have just finished a little project with Ti*k*Z library `shapes.geometric` so thought I would give my 2¢ here. Nothing terribly complicated subtle here -- just straightforward Ti*k*Z. There are comments in the code to help. Try `regular polygon sides=4` or `5` or `6`.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[rgb]{xcolor} %% If you use \pyramidhue, you will need this; TikZ does not work with hsb
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,positioning}

%% |=====8><-----| %%

\tikzset{tri/.style={%
        regular polygon,
        regular polygon sides=3, %% For fun, vary this number at will
        minimum size=#1,
        draw,
        thick,
        anchor=north
    },
    ptext/.style={font=\bfseries,align=center,text width=0.8*\pyrsize}
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\pyramid}{sO{}mm}{% #3 size; #4 entries
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\incrrate}{0.75}% The rate at which the triangles decrease in size
        \coordinate (T) at (0,0);
        \foreach \test/\testi [count=\testnum from 1] in {#4}{\xdef\tot{\testnum}}%
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\incr}{#3/\tot}
        \foreach \step/\col [count=\stepnum from 0] in {#4}{%
            \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\pyrsize}{#3-\incrrate*\stepnum*\incr}
            \node[tri=\pyrsize,fill=\col] (T\stepnum) at (T) {};
            \ifnum\stepnum=\numexpr\tot-1\relax
                \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\lift}{0.0*\incr*\incrrate}% raise text in top shape
            \else
                \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\lift}{0.1*\incr*\incrrate}% raise text in remaining shapes
            \fi
            \node[above=\lift of T\stepnum.south,ptext] {\step\strut};
        }%
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\pyramidshade}{sO{}mmm}{% #3 size; #4 base shade; #5 entries
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\incrrate}{0.75}% The rate at which the triangles decrease in size
        \coordinate (T) at (0,0);
        \foreach \test [count=\testnum from 1] in {#5}{\xdef\tot{\testnum}}%
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\incr}{#3/\tot}
        \foreach \step [count=\stepnum from 0] in {#5}{%
            \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\pyrsize}{#3-\incrrate*\stepnum*\incr}
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\shade}{(\tot-\stepnum)/\tot*100}
            \node[tri=\pyrsize,fill=#4!\shade] (T\stepnum) at (T) {};
            \ifnum\stepnum=\numexpr\tot-1\relax
                \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\lift}{0.1*\incr*\incrrate}% raise text in top shape
            \else
                \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\lift}{0.1*\incr*\incrrate}% raise text in remaining shapes
            \fi
            \node[above=\lift of T\stepnum.south,ptext] {\step\strut};
        }%
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\pyramidhue}{sO{}mm}{% #3 size; #4 entries
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\incrrate}{0.75}% The rate at which the triangles decrease in size
        \coordinate (T) at (0,0);
        \foreach \test [count=\testnum from 1] in {#4}{\xdef\tot{\testnum}}%
        \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\incr}{#3/\tot}
        \foreach \step [count=\stepnum from 0] in {#4}{%
            \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\pyrsize}{#3-\incrrate*\stepnum*\incr}
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\myhue}{(\tot-\stepnum)/\tot}%
            \definecolor{mycolor}{hsb}{\myhue,0.5,1}% See xcolor docs v2.12, page 18 ff.
            \node[tri=\pyrsize,fill=mycolor] (T\stepnum) at (T) {};
            \ifnum\stepnum=\numexpr\tot-1\relax
                \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\lift}{0.0*\incr*\incrrate}% raise text in top shape
            \else
                \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\lift}{0.1*\incr*\incrrate}% raise text in remaining shapes
            \fi
            \node[above=\lift of T\stepnum.south,ptext] {\step\strut};
        }%
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}

%% |=====8><-----| %%

\begin{document}

\centering

\pyramid{3.0in}{Non-League/green,League Two/blue!50!white,League One/yellow,Championship/blue!70!white,Premier\\League/orange}

\bigskip

\pyramidshade{3.0in}{purple!70!red!50!white}{Non-League,League Two,League One,Championship,Premier\\League}

\bigskip

\pyramidhue{3.0in}{Non-League,League Two,League One,Championship,Premier\\League}


\end{document}
```

[image: pyramid of shades]