# Draw a graph with vertex pairs

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, ubuntu, tikz-graphs, tikz-graphdrawing

I want to draw in LaTex a Petersen Graph using Kneser graph K(2,5) notation.
And i'll do the same with the hypercube.
Like this exemple:
How can i do it please ?
[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have.  See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The labeling of this graph is based on the [Kneser notation example in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kneser_graph).

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}

\tikzset{c/.style={draw,circle,fill=black,minimum size=4pt,inner sep=0pt,
anchor=center},
d/.style={draw,circle,fill=white,minimum size=4pt,inner sep=0pt, anchor=center}}
% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/294254/121799
\def\colorlist{{"cyan", "red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "gray", "blue", "violet"}}

\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\tiny]
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\Ncorners}{5}
\node[regular polygon,regular polygon sides=\Ncorners,minimum size=3cm] 
(poly\Ncorners) {};
\node[draw,regular polygon,regular polygon sides=\Ncorners,minimum size=5cm] 
(outerpoly\Ncorners) {};
\foreach\x in {1,...,\Ncorners}{
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\myprevx}{ifthenelse(\x==1,5,mod(\Ncorners+\x-1,\Ncorners))}
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\mynextx}{mod(\Ncorners+\x,\Ncorners)+1}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\myfill{\colorlist[\myprevx]}
    \node[d,label={{18+\x*72}:{$\{\myprevx,\mynextx\}$}},color=\myfill] (outerpoly\Ncorners-\x) at (outerpoly\Ncorners.corner \x){};
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\myprevx}{ifthenelse(\x==2,5,mod(\Ncorners+\x-2,\Ncorners))}
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\mynextx}{mod(\Ncorners+\x+1,\Ncorners)+1}
    \ifcase\x
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\ang}{0}  
    \or
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\ang}{0}
    \or 
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\ang}{90}     
    \or 
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\ang}{120}        
    \or 
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\ang}{60}     
    \or 
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\ang}{90}     
    \fi
    \pgfmathsetmacro\myfill{\colorlist[\myprevx]}
    \node[d,label={{\ang}:{$\{\myprevx,\mynextx\}$}},color=\myfill] (poly\Ncorners-\x) at (poly\Ncorners.corner \x){};
    \draw (poly\Ncorners-\x) -- (outerpoly\Ncorners-\x);
}
\foreach\X in {1,...,\Ncorners}{
\foreach\Y in {1,...,\Ncorners}{
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\Z}{abs(mod(abs(\Ncorners+\X-\Y),\Ncorners)-2)}
\ifnum\Z=0
\draw (poly\Ncorners-\X) -- (poly\Ncorners-\Y);
\fi
}
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**UPDATE**: Colors.

Comment: Thank u, can i ask you for the coloring ? For exemple; red for {5,2},{3,2},{2,1},{2,4}, blue for {1,3}, {4,3}, {4,1}, and green for {5,4}, {1,5}, {3,5}.
You're code is a little bit complicated for me, so i don't find how to do it. I used to do simple \node for vertex and \draw for bridges so...

Comment: This code uses simple nodes for the vertices and draw for the bridges, but in a foreach loop and using the predefined corners of regular polygons. What do you want to have colored, vertices, texts, or both? And is there a mathematical pattern for the coloring, which can be implemented in the loop?

Comment: I work on the chromatic number, so i want to have the vertices minimal coloring, there are many alghorithms that gives this coloration. In its simplest form, it is a way of coloring the vertices of a graph such that no two adjacent vertices share the same color.

Comment: @MassylKaci Meaning that I can take the color according to the index of one of its neighbors?

Comment: But it's not the optimum, we only need 3 colors for the Petersen's graph, as i said 
color 1 for {5,2},{3,2},{2,1},{2,4}, 
color 2 for{1,3}, {4,3}, {4,1}
color 3 for {5,4}, {1,5}, {3,5}

Comment: For exemple, {5,2} and {1,3} can't take the same color, because they don't have a number in commun.

Comment: @MassylKaci In your original question, there was no mention of colors. Then you asked for colors, and I added colors. Now you ask me to write a code according to your instructions. Why can't you do that yourself? Each of the nodes has a name and you can do whatever you like with it.