# How to make equal space between lines in a hierarchy pyramid

Tags: tikz-pgf, color

I used examples from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110522/how-to-elegantly-create-a-pyramid-hierarchy-in-tikz) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/294244/tikz-pyramid-hierarchy-colour) to draw my pyramid. I only need 3 sections and I am in wired position where I know how to have a pyramid with equal spacing and another with color, but not both. I would like to have the top pyramid (shape) with colors. Also I would like to know how to change the shape in the bottom pyramid, because just changing the coordinates results in 3 overlapping triangles.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,backgrounds}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (A) at (-5,0) {};
\coordinate (B) at ( 5,0) {};
\coordinate (C) at (0,7) {};
\draw[name path=AC] (A) -- (C);
\draw[name path=BC] (B) -- (C);
\foreach \y/\A in {
0/bottom,
2/middle ,
4/hoch} {
    \path[name path=horiz] (A|-0,\y) -- (B|-0,\y);
    \draw[name intersections={of=AC and horiz,by=P},
          name intersections={of=BC and horiz,by=Q}] (P) -- (Q)
          node[midway,above,align=center,text width=
\dimexpr(6em-\y em)*5\relax] {\A};
}
\end{tikzpicture}


\begin{tikzpicture}[x=2.5cm,y=2cm]
\coordinate (A) at (-3,-1) {};
\coordinate (B) at (3,-1) {};
\coordinate (C) at (0,5) {};
\foreach \A/\col [count=\i] in {bottom/yellow,middle/blue,top/orange}
\draw[fill=\col] (C)--([shift={(-.5*\i,1*\i)}]B)--node[above,align=center] {\A}([shift={(.5*\i,1*\i)}]A)--cycle; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: pyramid equally divided]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \def\r{5} % Radius of your triangle
        
        \foreach \i in {1,2,3} \coordinate (\i) at (90+120*\i:\r);
        \draw[fill=orange] (1) -- (2) node[above,midway] {bottom} -- (3) -- cycle;
        \path (1) -- (3) coordinate[pos=0.33] (a1) coordinate[pos=0.66] (a2);
        \path (2) -- (3) coordinate[pos=0.33] (b1) coordinate[pos=0.66] (b2);
        \foreach \i/\clr/\txt in {1/blue/middle,2/yellow/top} \draw[fill=\clr] (3) -- (b\i) -- (a\i) node[above,midway] {\txt} -- cycle;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```