# Stacked 3D Pyramid - Modify

Tags: tikz-pgf, geometry, 3d, tikz-graphdrawing

Sorry to come back to an old post.
I was reviewing this discussion:
[Stacked 3D Pyramid](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/341480/stacked-3d-pyramid)
And trying to work on Guilherme's answer, where he adds shading. Following on this, I was trying to do something similar but dividing the three parts of the pyramid according to their share in the total volume. For example: that the first part corresponds to 60%, that the middle part corresponds to 30% and that the top of the pyramid represents 10% of the volume of the complete pyramid. While I understand that this would require modifying some height-related commands, it has been difficult for me to modify the code to obtain an appropriate result. I would appreciate any comments.
Thank you in advance to anyone who masters tikz.
Best of luck.

Comment: I don't think this should have been a post. Instead, you should have asked for a clarification from Guilherme there. I understand it is 2016 though... For the answer, you can see that he used this line `\coordinate (\n\level b) at ($(\n)!\lastlevel/\levels+\levelsep/2!(H)$);}}` to define the coordinates for each level. He used a `foreach` loop for that. You have to modify it to have it define the coordinates lower proportionally to the values you specified (60,30,10%)