# How to draw a pyramid like this in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, overleaf

I want to draw a pyramid-like this using tikz.
I would be really happy if someone could help me !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)! Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. Did you search on this site for e.g "pyramid" ? I straight away got a hit like https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/217625/draw-a-pyramid-with-tikz What did you try so far, what problems did you encounter?

Comment: I already use this code but i want to add the comments beside the pyramid for more explanation

Comment: So please sow what you tried